# How can I make another scene after scanning the image target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Good day everyone,
how can I make another scene after scanning the image target? So far I can only do the buttons which are the basics and am currently working with c#, visual studio, unity and vuforia.
Iv'e done the main menu screen which has the buttons `scan` and `exit`. Whenever you click the scan button it will automatically go to the AR camera and my question is how can I make a AR camera which you can scan an image and go to the another scene. No animation or whatsoever, just scan the image and go to another scene. Does someone has an idea of how to make it happen?

so far this is what iv'e coded:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {
    public void System()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex +1);
    }
    public void Back()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex -1);
    }
    public void Exit()
    {
        Debug.Log("You have exited the app");
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can just create a gameobject as a child of your `image target`, attach a script, lets say `sceneloader.cs` and put in the `start()` method your load-scene-code....but this are total basics. Did you even read the documentation how image targets work?

Comment: no  i didn't i just go straight ahead to the tutorials and work on my project.

Comment: is there any tutorials that are available in the web where i can copy it?